# XRMToolbox cannot connect to Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

I'm using the XRMToolbox normally and it suddenly cannot connect to Dynamics CRM anymore. I still can access to dynamic CRM normally but now I cannot using XRMToolbox. This is the error message.

[image]

Do you guys have any recommendations???

Comment: Did anything change recently - password, two-factor auth, proxy, firewall?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reset the password. Still dont know what is the root cause of this issue :D

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same however have it now working via an **SDK Login Control** connection and next **Office 365** sign-in (instead of the earlier Connection Wizard connections which seemed to stop working)